# Mean.io Fetch all accounts for a given user on login

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, mean-stack

I have two models, User and Account. When a user signs up, an account is automatically generated for him and he becomes the owner of that account like so:

*Account document*

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54f3391c96bfc9fb0b46f088"),
    "account" : "Company Name",
    "auth_token" : "test auth token",
    "owner" : ObjectId("54f3391c96bfc9fb0b46f087"),
    "users" : [ 
        ObjectId("54f3391c96bfc9fb0b46f087")
    ],
    "__v" : 0
}
```

Users can also be assigned to other accounts, this is saved in the *users* attribute for the account, *Users* and *owner* are subdocuments.

Now I would like to ensure that when a user logs in, I fetch a list of all the accounts accessible by that user, so that I can build a UI for switching account.

I have not idea how to approach the issue, any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your login route/controller do something like:

```
Account.find({ owner: req.user._id }, function(err, accounts){
  console.log(accounts)
})
```

Comment: In the account controller? How do I make it available to the front-end?

Comment: That is a really broad question, but generally through a REST API. Your original question solely dealt with how to get a list of accounts.

Comment: Thanks, that's true but that only covers the query aspect of it, which I have covered. My question is on where should I enter that code to execute on login and where/how should I stored the results...any idea?

Comment: You should do some research, try some things out, and once you narrow down on your problem post some code, else there's just too much to explain.